# Combine two list as key value pair using zip if lists have same values

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two lists:

```
yy = ['Inside the area', 'Inside the area', 'Inside the area', 'Inside the area', 'Inside the area', 'Inside the area', 'Outside the area']
lat_ = [77.2167, 77.25, 77.2167, 77.2167, 77.2, 77.2167, 77.2]
```

I am combining them using the solution given on some posts here by:

```
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(yy, lat_)}
print new_dict
```

But my output is `{'Inside the area': 77.2167, 'Outside the area': 77.2}`

This is happening because the most of the keys are same. I am doing this because I want to map these two list in order to get which values of lat falls inside or outside, and then keep only the ones which fall inside.

Comment: If the `inside the area` key needs to have many values, why are you trying to use a dictionary ? If you still want to, you could make lists for dictionary values, which could hold multiple values for one key.

Comment: But then the problem would be this: consider the situation when the key Inside are maps to a 77.216 and at the same time the key outside are maps to same value. Please note both the lists are a output of two different functions.That is the reason I am not combining it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zip them and add a guard inside a list comprehension:

```
res = [lat for a, lat in zip(yy, lat_) if a.startswith(“Inside”)]
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep the values that are inside:

#### Code:

```
for k, v in zip(yy, lat_):
    if k.startswith('Inside'):
        inside.append(v)
```

#### Test Code:

```
yy = ['Inside the area', 'Inside the area', 'Inside the area',
      'Inside the area', 'Inside the area', 'Inside the area',
      'Outside the area']
lat_ = [77.2167, 77.25, 77.2167, 77.2167, 77.2, 77.2167, 77.2]

inside = []
for k, v in zip(yy, lat_):
    if k.startswith('Inside'):
        inside.append(v)
print(inside)
```

#### Results:

```
[77.2167, 77.25, 77.2167, 77.2167, 77.2, 77.2167]
```