# Map dictionary values to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary whose values are a list:

```
dict ={10: ['jhon', 'abc', 'wa@gmail.com'], 12: ['raghav', 'awdaw', 'raghavpatnecha15@gmail.com']}
```

Now I am accessing them like this:
 `dict[10][0]`

But It makes so confusing as I don't know what is at index 0 in my list for a particular key.

For this I have another list which helps me what is at index i.

```
['Manager Name', 'Owner Name', 'Email']
```

So know this makes easy to access the values of my dictionary. Like I want to use: `dict[10]['Manager Name']` instead of `dict[10][0]`

Is this achievable in Python. Because I tried reference from [Map two list in to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729976/combine-two-list-as-key-value-pair-using-zip-if-lists-have-same-values?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) But how do I map a dictionary values to a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just restructure your dictionary into a nested dictionary:

```
d_input = {10: ['jhon', 'abc', 'wa@gmail.com'],
           12: ['raghav', 'awdaw', 'raghavpatnecha15@gmail.com']}

d = {k: {'Manager Name': a, 'Owner Name': b, 'Email': c} \
        for k, (a, b, c) in d_input.items()}
```

Result:

```
{10: {'Email': 'wa@gmail.com', 'Manager Name': 'jhon', 'Owner Name': 'abc'},
 12: {'Email': 'raghavpatnecha15@gmail.com', 'Manager Name': 'raghav', 'Owner Name': 'awdaw'}}
```

---

Extendible version with `zip`:

```
cats = ['Manager Name', 'Owner Name', 'Email']

d = {k: dict(zip(cats, v)) for k, v in d_input.items()}
```

Comment: what if the length of my list and the dictionary value list is variable.Lets say in this example the length is 3 but it can be 8 if I add more parameters. I don't want to add more (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h).

Answer (score 3):

This is a clear use case for [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Instead of having lists that represent companies like `['jhon', 'abc', 'wa@gmail.com']`, python gives you the possibility to model that as a *class*:

```
class Company:
    def __init__(self, manager_name, owner_name, email):
        self.manager_name = manager_name
        self.owner_name = owner_name
        self.email = email

companies = {10: Company('jhon', 'abc', 'wa@gmail.com'),
             12: Company('raghav', 'awdaw', 'raghavpatnecha15@gmail.com'}
```

This gives you a much nicer interface than a list, because you can access the attributes by name rather than by index:

```
>>> comp = Company('jhon', 'abc', 'wa@gmail.com')
>>> comp.manager_name
'jhon'
>>> comp.owner_name
'abc'
>>> comp.email
'wa@gmail.com'
```

---

If you're lazy and don't want to define the `Company` class manually, you can use [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to reduce the amount of code you have to write:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Company = namedtuple('Company', 'manager_name owner_name email')
```

---

You can also convert your dict of lists to a dict of `Company` instances easily:

```
companies = {10: ['jhon', 'abc', 'wa@gmail.com'],
             12: ['raghav', 'awdaw', 'raghavpatnecha15@gmail.com']}

comps = {num: Company(*comp) for num, comp in companies.items()}
# result:
# {10: Company(manager_name='jhon', owner_name='abc', email='wa@gmail.com'),
#  12: Company(manager_name='raghav', owner_name='awdaw', email='raghavpatnecha15@gmail.com')}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your "attributes" are always exactly `['Manager Name', 'Owner Name', 'Email']`, you should consider using namedtuples or the new `dataclass` of Python 3.7.

Here is an example using namedtuples:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Company = namedtuple('Company', ['manager', 'owner', 'email'])

comp = Company('jhon', 'abc', 'wa@gmail.com')
print(comp.manager, comp.owner, comp.email)
```

results in `jhon abc wa@gmail.com`

Answer (score 1):

You should use [named tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python).

Your code could look like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Company = namedtuple('Company', 'ManagerName OwnerName Email')

c1 = Company('jhon', 'abc', 'wa@gmail.com')
c2 =  Company('raghav', 'awdaw', 'raghavpatnecha15@gmail.com')

companies = {10: c1, 12: c2}
companies[10].Email
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the dictionary, you can use another dictionary to map the indices to the corresponding values.

```
>>> d = {10: ['jhon', 'abc', 'wa@gmail.com'], 12: ['raghav', 'awdaw', 'raghavpatnecha15@gmail.com']}    
>>> mapper = {'Manager Name': 0, 'Owner Name': 1, 'Email': 2}    
>>> d[10][mapper['Manager Name']]
'jhon'
>>> d[12][mapper['Email']]
'raghavpatnecha15@gmail.com'
```